# Accessing the associated join model when iterating through a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a feeling this is a pretty basic question, but for some reason I'm stumped by it (Rails newbie) and can't seem to find the answer (which may be I'm not searching properly).

So I have a basic has_many :through relationship like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts, through :user_contacts

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through :user_contacts
```

In users/show.html.erb I'm iterating through a single user's contacts, like:

```
<% @user.contacts.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
```

Now inside of that each loop, I want to access the user_contact join model that's associated with the given user and contact in order to display the created_at timestamp that indicates when the user <--> contact relationship was made.

I know I could just do a UserContact.find call to look up the model in the database by the user_id and contact_id but somehow this feels superfluous. If I understand correctly how this works (it's entirely possible I don't) the user_contact model should have already been loaded when I loaded the given user and its contacts from the database already. I just don't know how to properly access the correct model. Can someone help with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the join model will not have been loaded yet: ActiveRecord takes the `through` specification to build its SQL `JOIN` statements for querying the correct `Contact` records but effectively will only instantiate those.

Assuming you have a `UserContact` model, you could do sth like this:

```
@user.user_contacts.includes(:contact).find_each do |uc|
    # now you can access both join model and contact without additional queries to the DB
end
```

If you want to keep things readable without cluttering your code with `uc.contact.something`, you can set up delegations inside the `UserContact` model that delegate some properties to `contact` or `user` respectively. For example this

```
class UserContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact
  delegate :name, to: :contact, prefix: true
end
```

would allow you to write

```
uc.contact_name
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `has_many :things, through: :other_things` clause is going to look for the `other_things` relationship to find `:things`.

Think of it as a method call of sorts with magic built in to make it performant in SQL queries. So by using a `through` clause you're more or less doing something like:

```
def contacts
  user_contacts.map { |user_contact| user_contact.contacts }.flatten
end
```

The context of the `user_contacts` is completely lost.

Since it looks like `user_contacts` is a one-to-one join. It would be easier to do something like this:

```
<% @user.user_contacts.each do |user_contact| %>
  <%= user_contact.contact.name %>
<% end %>
```

Also since you're new to Rails it's worth mentioning that to load those records without an N+1 query you can do something like this in your controller:

```
@user = User.includes(user_contacts: [:contacts]).find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks, got this working. One clarification for anyone who stumbles on this in the future, the correct syntax for the includes is BEFORE the .find: @user = User.includes(user_contacts: [:contact]).find(params[:id])

Comment: Ahh, you're right. `find` doesn't return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Thanks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.joins` and `.select` in this way:

`@contacts = current_user.contacts.joins(user_contacts: :users).select('contacts.*, user_contacts.user_contact_attribute_name as user_contact_attribute_name')`

Now, inside `@contacts.each do |contact|` loop, you can call `contact.user_contact_attribute_name`.

It looks weird because `contact` doesn't have that `user_contact_attribute_name`, only `UserContact` does, but the `.select` portion of the query will make that magically available to you on each `contact` instance.

The `contacts.*` portion is what tells the query to make all `contact`'s attributes available as well.